# Find the integer part

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Sorry I failed to type it.

> The integer part of $$\sqrt{2\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt[4]{4\cdots \sqrt[2011]{2011}}}}$$
>   is...

My Atempt:

As $2011<2^{11}$ I tried to write the expression between two power of $2$ , but things are quickly becoming very ugly. I think there may another neat way. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: prove by induction for $n = 2011, 2010, \ldots, 2$ that $\sqrt[n]{n \sqrt[n+1]{n+1 \ldots \sqrt[2011]{2011}}} < 2$ using the fact that $2m \leqslant 2^m$ for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(\sqrt[\large2]{2\sqrt[\large3]{3\sqrt[\large4]{4\ldots \sqrt[\large n]{n}}}}\right)
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{\log(k)}{k!}\tag{1a}\\
&\lt(e-2)\frac1{e-2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\log(k)}{k!}\tag{1b}\\
&\lt(e-2)\log\left(\frac1{e-2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k}{k!}\right)\tag{1c}\\
&=(e-2)\log\left(\frac{e-1}{e-2}\right)\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a:)}$ write the log of a product as the sum of logs
$\text{(1b:)}$ multiply by $\frac{e-2}{e-2}$ and sum to $\infty$
$\text{(1c:)}$ $\log$ is stricly concave; apply Jensen's Inequality: $\frac1{e-2}\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k!}=1$
$\text{(1d:)}$ $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k}{k!}=e-1$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt[\large2]{2\sqrt[\large3]{3\sqrt[\large4]{4\ldots \sqrt[\large n]{n}}}}
&\lt\left(\frac{e-1}{e-2}\right)^{e-2}\tag{2a}\\
&=\left(1+\frac1{e-2}\right)^{e-2}\tag{2b}\\
&\lt1+\frac{e-2}{e-2}\tag{2c}\\[6pt]
&=2\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ apply $(1)$
$\text{(2b):}$ $\frac{e-1}{e-2}=1+\frac1{e-2}$
$\text{(2c):}$ Bernoulli's Inequality for exponents in $(0,1)$
$\text{(2d):}$ evaluate

We can verify $(2)$ numerically:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[\large2]{2\sqrt[\large3]{3\sqrt[\large4]{4\ldots \sqrt[\large n]{n}}}}&=1.829024679564\tag{3a}\\
\left(\frac{e-1}{e-2}\right)^{e-2}&=1.871047488042\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Great work for an answer.

Comment: This question is mentioned on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h99441p561410), but the link to the answer and discussion is broken. I saw a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4840103) here, and asked this question in a comment. I have not seen an answer elsewhere on the net.