# A nice finite induction problem: $\sqrt{2 \sqrt{3 \sqrt{4 \ldots \sqrt{n}}}}<3.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\sqrt{2 \sqrt{3 \sqrt{4 \ldots \sqrt{n}}}}<3.$$
Any help proving this problem by finite induction. I tried to use $\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt[4]{3}\cdot\sqrt[8]{4}\cdots\sqrt[2^{n-1}]{n}<3$ as a hypothesis, but I was not successful. I'm trying to resolve this issue in my article, which brings together questions like this.

Comment: If $s_n = \sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\cdots\sqrt n}}}$, then for an inductive approach you want to find a relationship between $s_{n+1}$ and $s_n$. In this case, perhaps $s_{n+1} = \sqrt{s_n} {{}\times{}}$(something)...?

Comment: Are the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3721694) sufficient?

Comment: Here is a related bound: $$\sqrt[\large3]{2\sqrt[\large3]{3\sqrt[\large3]{4\ldots \sqrt[\large3]{n}}}}\lt\sqrt{5/2}$$

Comment: Or even more interesting: $$ \sqrt[\large2]{2\sqrt[\large3]{3\sqrt[\large4]{4\ldots \sqrt[\large n]{n}}}}\lt\left(\frac{e-1}{e-2}\right)^{e-2} $$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then
$$\sqrt{2 \sqrt{3 \sqrt{4 \ldots \sqrt{n}}}}=\prod_{k=2}^n\sqrt[2^{k-1}]{k}=\prod_{k=2}^n\exp({2^{1-k}\ln{k}})=\exp\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{\ln{k}}{2^{k-1}}\right).$$
Can you find an upper bound for that sum?

Comment: I can't understand this level of mathematics well, sorry!